# How to set an env variable's value as null

Tags: spring, hibernate, null, environment-variables

Sorry if it's a repeat question. I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

My java application expects a password through an environment variable.

My staging environment doesn't have any password setup. How can I send a null value to the java application through env variable?

```
export pass=
```

If I put the above ^ in my ~/.bash_rc file, it isn't working.

**EDIT :**

I'm using spring & hibernate and taking the value in the XML. Something like the below:

```
<bean id="myclass" class="mu.package.Myclass">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${pass}"/>
</bean>
```

If I replace `${pass}` with `${pass:#{null}}` to handle null checks with spel, it always takes the null value because the value is not present as a property but as an env variable. Is it possible for `${pass:#{null}}` to check both properties & env variable before assigning null value?

Comment: Hm, maybe you can share your Java code... but why not just check for null or empty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your configuration has defined a `PropertyPlaceHolder` element in the XML:

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

Then you simply need to make sure that by setting up the system environment variable that it is named exactly the same as your XML configuration expects for it to be translated.